# Help designing Board game using LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, game-loop, scene2d

Hi i'd just like to preface this by saying i'm new to game development and currently learning the ins and outs of libGDX.

I want to create the board game scrabble however i'm having trouble figuring out how i would display the board and the pieces each player has.

So in my game the board will probably be 14x14 , each player (4 maximum) at the start of the game will have about 6 letter tiles in their hand. The player whos turn it is , is able to place letter tiles from their hand onto the board and do so until a word is spelt on the board. The player should also be able to pick up individual letter tiles that they have placed down.

From searching on the internet I figured out that i should probably make the board a 2d array of either actors or buttons. For example, the player would click on the letter tile and then click on the board and the tile would be placed. However, as there is limited information online about libGDX in the form of tutorials I do not have a complete solid understanding of this. If anyone could help me understand how I would go about implementing my ideas i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. As is, your question seems like a very broad, "how do I get started with X" sort of question. Both those qualities are likely to get it closed as they are considered not [on-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the more specific QA format here. Is it possible for you do narrow your question to a specific, focused problem your having with libGDX?

Comment: @Pikalek Yeah sure. I guess everything comes down to: what is the best way to pass information between actors and for them to display the new information. For example a player can have the letters (x y i o) in their hand and then they click on the board after clicking on any letter in their hand and the letter is then displayed on the board.

Comment: If that's your question, then edit the post above to describe that problem in detail.